# Android Imageview regions

Tags: android, imageview, regions

i have a little problem. I have a ImageView and there an image placed. I would now  divided this into regions. If I, for example, Click on the center, to be issued to me a message (toast). I like implemented before in C #. In Android, however, I do not know exactly how this should go.

Comment: Have you tried anything in android yourself?

Comment: https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: [Multi Region Image View](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33444416/1841194)